# Can't access internet on my college wifi. Login page doesn't show up

Tags: wireless

I just switched from windows to Ubuntu and I don't know much about it and when I connect it to my college wifi, the login page doesn't load automatically. In windows it opened as soon as I connected to the wifi. I am very new to Ubuntu so please answer elaborately. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are expecting a website page to pop open for login to the college network and that it is not popping open. I believe new connections are forced to a login page by a redirect link sent to your web browser (so you cannot access other pages until you successfully get through that login).

If all of this is correct and the browser redirect is not working for whatever reason, you may be able to learn the URL of the login page from a system administrator (or knowledgeable user at the college) or to see what it is from a newly connected user who gets redirected to the page and then to manually enter the URL into your browser.

I have heard that some browsers may prevent access to some login-type pages. You may wish to try opening up a different browser and heading to a favorite web page just to see if the redirect to the login takes over. (I hope that's helpful.)

Answer (score 2):

Try to load some website such as https://www.bing.com or https://www.google.com . That probably will automatically redirect you to the login page.

Sometimes, https://www.google.com doesn't work in chrome. I've seen this happen if your college network login page uses local invalid certificate and chrome never lets your redirect to such a page from "https" google.com